# How to get and process an XML Response after making an HTTP Request

Tags: java, xml, web-services, sax

I have an iterative method that will make 100's of calls to a url and then parse the XML response and persist the data after each call.

To accomplish this I have been trying to just use HttpURLConnection to get the response, convert it into a string, and then a document so I can process it and parse the tags/info I want using SAX.

However, this method only works sometimes, intermediately I get the following exception:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

The issue appears to be that the XML String doesn't always come back properly. Instead of getting the normal XML tag with the data in between like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> </xml>`

I get something like this:

`{"created":"2019-03-18T13:19:41.484Z","count":3654,"offset":500 ....`

The string contains the data that I need, but for some reason it seems like the response doesn't always return it in the form I need. I have confirmed that this is an intermittent issue, meaning I have hit the same exact request and sometimes received the desired response and at others received the undesired response.

**Method that makes the request**

```
URL url = new URL("Some URL");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

if (responseCode != 200) {
    log.error("Received an invalid response: " + responseCode);
    return;
}

parseXml(convertResponseToXmlString(connection));

connection.disconnect();
```

**Method that converts the response into a String**

```
private String convertResponseToXmlString(final HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException
{
    String inputLine;

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }

    input.close();

    return content.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: What you're getting back is JSON. So, either the server is always (or randomly) sending back JSON, and you'll need to use a JSON parser instead of a XML parser when the content type header (if it's properly set) indicates that the response contains JSON, or the server actually sends you JSON because you didn't specifically ask for XML using the Accept header of your request.

Comment: Looks like the server to which you are placing a call answers JSON or XML, depending on... "whatever it feels like". So this is probably not SAX, XML, or java related at all. As long as the server switches format for no reasong whatsoever, you will be stuck trying to adapt. Nevertheless : why does the server switch format ? Read its API documentation, and maybe... just try adding a "Accept: application/xml" header to the http request. It's the usual way to say that you definitely want XML in the response.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the server chooses randomly between XML and JSON responses, but multiple load-balanced servers behind the same URL conceivably might be differently configured, which could look the same.  Very likely the service has a means to specify which response form you want.  If so, then you should use it, and if you then get a response in a different format than requested you should report a bug to the server operator.

Answer (score 1):

`connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");`

should help :)
or else try:

`connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, you are totally right. I needed to add a request param to the request URL that specified that I wanted the data to be returned as XML.

Weird that the response varied like that, but its fixed now!